# Which popular learning-based algorithms cannot be kernelized?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, kernel-trick

**Question:** Out of the most popular learning-based algorithms, which cannot be kernelized? I am aware that "popular" is rather ambiguous, I cannot give an exact search space but it should encompasses methods likely seen during a senior year Bachelor's course on Machine Learning.

**What I know:** I have already by hand derived kernelized linear regression with(out) ridge penalty and have seen kernelized logistic regression.

**Why I'm asking:** While prepping for an exam, I encountered a multiple choice question about which popular learning algorithms cannot be kernelized. The selection contained many algorithms for which we during the lecture never explicitly discussed how to kernelize them and the time alloted for the question does not allow in-depth reasoning about each option.

Comment: At the introductory level, and under appropriate conditions, the appearance of a dot product in your algorithm invites the use of the kernel trick.

Comment: why don't you list the algorithms you know and put against them whether you think they can be kernelized